# Java-utilizing programs malfunctioning

Tags: java, display

Ok so I've had this problem for as long as I've had this computer.
Almost all programs which utilize java in some way seem to be malfunctioning, e.g Geogebra, Maple, MarvinSketch etc.
The problem is hard to describe but it's some kind of image distortion that changes when the cursor is moved around.

Funny enough Java IDE software such as Eclipse and JCreator work just fine, the programs on them as well.

Here are some pictures:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8FJefOEBlXEWm4yR0I5bHBVX0U/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8FJefOEBlXEZEpRYmhleW1KdFE/view?usp=sharing

Things I have tried:Reinstall Java (duh),cleared Java cache, tried every possible compatibility settings, reinstalled the malfunctioning programs

I am currently running the latest version of java (both 32 and 64 bit) on Windows 10.

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me on this one, as Google couldn't.

P.S: There are no issues with the hardware performance and all drivers are up to date.

Comment: Flagged to migrate to SuperUser, probably the better site for this.  Also, can't see those images.

Comment: "Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at drive.google.com."